# Duplicating a record in Access and Appending to a table with one field changed

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am a newbie when it comes to programming Access, so I kindly ask for some help please. I have a table with 6 fields:

```
PolicyNum, Name, Address, InsuredValue, Status, DuplicateNumber
```

Under the *Status* field, if the value for a record states 'Duplicate', then I need to copy that record, append to another table (*tblPolicies*), and then repeat that step but this time append same record, but with a '-01' as a suffix added to the *PolicyNum*. I might need to duplicate that record a few times and suffix '-02', '-03', etc depending on the number under the *DuplicateNumber* field. So, as an example, I have:

```
PolicyNum, Name, Address, InsuredValue, Status, DuplicateNumber
FL65875, John Doe, 545 Anywhere Street, $10000, Duplicate, 2
```

So, I would append the exact record as it appears above to *tblPolicies*, but need to duplicate it because it is denoted as such under *Status*, and I need to duplicate it two times...so I'd need to append two more records with below changes to *PolicyNum*:

```
PolicyNum, Name, Address, InsuredValue, Status, DuplicateNumber
FL65875-01, John Doe, 545 Anywhere Street, $10000, Duplicate, 2
FL65875-02, John Doe, 545 Anywhere Street, $10000, Duplicate, 2
```

As you can see from above, *PolicyNum* has -01 and -02 suffixed, and that's the only change. After the append, I would get rid of the Status and *DuplicateNumber* fields in the destination table of *tblPolicies*.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using recordset updates where you iterate through the source table and within a `For` loop add new records to destination table mapping fields accordingly with suffix concatenation on *PolicyNum*. Even ignore the last two columns since they are not needed.

```vb
Dim src_rst As Recordset, dest_rst as Recordset

Set src_rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE [Status] = 'Duplicate' AND DuplicateNumber > 0")    
Set dest_rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblPolicies")

src_rst.MoveFirst

Do While src_rst Not .EOF
   For i = 1 To src_rst![DuplicateNumber]
       dest_rst.AddNew

       dest_rst![PolicyNum] = src_rst![PolicyNum] & "-0" & i
       dest_rst![Name] = src_rst![Name]
       dest_rst![Address] = src_rst![Address]
       dest_rst![InsuredValue] = src_rst![InsuredValue]

       dest_rst.Update 
   Next i

   src_rst.MoveNext
Loop

dest_rst.Close(): src_rst.Close()
Set dest_rst = Nothing: src_rst = Nothing
```

Comment: The above code didn't work - I get a Run-time error '3021': No Current Record. When I debug, it highlights the For i =1 To src_rst![DuplicateNumber] line...I made sure the fileds and tables are exactly as they appear in above code.

Comment: Whoops! I had an incorrect *dups_rst* which you should have caught with [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) at top and regularly clicking Tools \ Debug. And I assume you are changing *mytable* in `SELECT` statement.